# Matching Multiple Keywords Exactly in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to search through 1000s of invoice lines to locate prices paid for services.

Essentially the format of each line is the same  going [Size][Container][Material][Process] the below image is an example.

sample image

[image]

I just want have a formula where I can select the range, and it will pick up any line item that has 3 keywords, but only those three, if it has 2 of the 3, it will ignore it etc.

So ideally I can then have a list of the lines that match that search function and the prices paid.

I hope someone can help, I've only managed to make it search for keywords in general but not exact matches

Comment: Where is the code you've written, what doesn't it do that you want it to do and where is the area that you are having btrouble with?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to quick filter according to 3 conditions at the same time. This is kind of easy using a helper filter column.

Please see the screenshot first:
[image]

**Filter** is our helper column, we will try to produce `TRUE` and `FALSE` values here according to the keywords you enter into `E1`, `F1` and `G1` cells. `TRUE` means the cell on the left has all those keywords.

The formula of `B2` is as follows and should be copied down:

```
=ISERROR(FIND(E$1,$A2)+FIND(F$1,$A2)+FIND(G$1,$A2))
```

The formula basically tries to find the location of 3 keywords in our description string and add them up. If one of them is not found, then an error is thrown and the sum will also be an error. I used this error to see whether all of the keywords exist in our string or not.

Finally you should open the filter for COL:A and COL:B and filter `TRUE` values to see only the rows containing your keywords.

Comment: I like. Especially if E1,F1,G1 are  dependant drop down lists! +1

Comment: I agree! If the options for filter values are limited and known, **Data Validation** can be used to show them in drop down lists.